# Wrapping divs inside a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is my situation and what I want the end result to be.
I tried using wrapAll() for .B but it ended up grouping every single .B div into one. I can't alter the html that's why I have to do it via jquery. Thanks!

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>

  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>

  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>


</div>
```

What I want to archive:

```
<div class="parent">

<div class="A"></div>
<div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</div>

<div class="A"></div>
<div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</div>

<div class="A"></div>
<div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to allow us to help you more efficiently (consider compiling your codes in a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would select all `.A` elements, then for each of them you search for all siblings until you find an other `.A` using [`.nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and warp them into a `div`

```
$('.A').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).nextUntil('.A').wrapAll('<div>'))
})
```

Comment: exactly what I need! Learned something new!